# Unable to scroll in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio 3.1 and for some reason I am unable to scroll through the code using the touchpad. I have to manually scroll by dragging the scroll bar on the right, and this can get very tedious and inconvenient if im working on a large project. I used to be able to two-finger scroll on previous versions of Android Studio but for some reason its just not working anymore. I have windows 10 if thats relevant. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Android Studio 3.1 has definitely an issue with touchpad scrolling but they don't seem to want to admit that!

Answer (score 0):

try to : minimized all open application and refresh window you can say the desktop where you see your wallpaper (Right click on window(HomeScreen)) and click refresh) then pop out And. Studio and press F5 .